# Option missing for content type: 'BI Semantic Model Connection' in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-2012, business-intelligence, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to add a new content type : BI Semantic Model Connection. But I don’t see it in the list of Available Site Content Types.

[image: Screenshot shows the missing option for BI Semantic Model Content type]

What is required to enable BISM Connection content type? Do I need to install any binary?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to Activate Power Pivot Feature Integration for Site Collections in Central Administration.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230813.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee637271.aspx